# How to read a text file in bottom up manner using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am working on a project which requires creation of certain resources, while creating resources i also write in a file to rollback that creation process if an error occurs. 
But there is a catch in here, the resources has to be deleted in just the opposite manner in which they were created, so when i write in roll back file like this :

```
delete R1
delete R2
..
..
delete RN
```

i want to delete the resources in order ->

```
delete RN
delete RN-1
....
...
delete R1
```

is there a way to do that in windows batch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no native way to read a file in reverse order using batch.

But, while not the fastest method, it can be solved reading the file in normal order, prefixing each line with a padded number, sorting the list in reverse order, splitting the line to separate the numbers and then process the list

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "file=data.txt"

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¬" %%a in ('
        cmd /v:off /e /q /c"set "counter^=10000000" & for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%c in ("%file%") do (set /a "counter+^=1" & echo(¬%%c)"
        ^| sort /r
    ') do (
        echo %%b
    )
```

How it works:

The code will, for each line in the input file, output a number prefix and the line, with a delimiter (`¬`) to later be able to separate both elements.

As later the data will be sorted, we need that the prefix has a uniform length. So we initialize the counter in `10000000` and increase it so the prefix in all lines has the same length (note: if your file has more than 99999999 lines, *please*, don't use this method)

To change the counter we will simply use a `set /a "counter+=1"`, but to echo it inside a loop we will need delayed expansion, but this could generate problems with the data readed from the file (I don't know if it can contain `!` characters).

We can enable/disable delayed expansion to handle it, but as this is necessary for each line, there will be a performance loss. To solve it, the code is executed in a separate `cmd` instance.

Why a separate instance? The code in this separate instance is executed not in a batch context, but in a command line context. In command line context the `set /a` command echoes the result of the calc, so we don't need to do it and the delayed expansion problem vanishes. We simply calculate the new counter (that gets echoed), and echo the delimiter and the line readed from the input file. So we have the following code

```dos
set "counter=10000000" 
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%c in ("%file%") do (
    set /a "counter+=1" 
    echo(¬%%c
)
```

It is written as a concatenated command and passed as argument to a `cmd` instance (note: `^` are used to escape problematic characters), that is executed with `echo off` (`/q`), extensions enabled (`/e`) and disabled delayed expansion (`/v:off`)

```dos
cmd /v:off /e /q /c"set "counter^=10000000" & for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%c in ("%file%") do (set /a "counter+^=1" & echo(¬%%c)"
```

This will generate the prefixed output. Now, to sort in reverse order, the output is piped to a `sort /r` command.

```dos
cmd /c"..." | sort /r
```

As the result of the pipe needs to be processed (in the sample we will only `echo` the line to console), the full pipe is executed inside the  `for /f %%a` (more `^` escape characters).

```dos
 for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¬" %%a in ('
      cmd /c"..." ^| sort /r
 ') do ....
```

This `for` command indicates that the `¬` character will be used as a delimiter to tokenize the input lines (the result of the pipe execution), and that we want to retrieve the first token (the number prefix, that will not be used but needs to be included) into `%%a` and the rest of the line (without additional splitting) in `%%b`.

So, at the end, the code in the `do` clause of the `for /f %%a` will be executed for each line in the input file, in reverse order, with the line stored in `%%b`.

Comment: what is the use of `¬` in `delims=¬" %%a` ? , also can you please explain your solution in more detail.

Comment: @SubhamTripathi, answer updated. Please, check if now it is clear enough.

Comment: which key are u pressing to print `¬` because i am not finding any in my keyboard :)

Comment: @SubhamTripathi, for me it is AltGr+6 (in a spanish keyboard), but you can copy/paste it or use almost any other character. Select a character that is not contained in your data or at least that does not match with the starting characters of each line. Just change the `echo` that includes the delimiter and the `delims` clause that uses it.

Comment: not working for me `alt + 6` , i understood your point though.

Answer (score 0):

This reverses the lines of text in a file.

**Swap**

```
filter swap
```

Reverses the lines in a file so the top line becomes the bottom line.

**Example**

```
cscript //nologo filter.vbs swap <"%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

From Filter.vbs from https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E2F0CE17A268A4FA!121 - 19 sample vbs programs for working with lines in files. It includes a batch file that makes using it easy.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    Dim LineCount
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "LineNumber", 4 
        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        LineCount = 0
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            LineCount = LineCount + 1
            .AddNew
            .Fields("LineNumber").value = LineCount
            .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
            .UpDate
        Loop
        .Sort = "LineNumber DESC"
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
```

Comment: sry but i needed a solution using plain batch , thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method :

```
Del /F /Q "%Temp%\File.Sort.Reverse.txt" >Nul: 2>&1
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F %%a In ('Type "FileName" ^| Find /C /V ""') Do Set /A File.Lines.Count=%%a
Set /A File.Lines.Count+=1
For /F %%a In ('Type "FileName') Do Set /A File.Lines.Count-=1 & Set "File.Line.Number=00000000000000000000!File.Lines.Count!" & @Echo.[!File.Line.Number:~-20!]%%a>>"%Temp%\File.Sort.Reverse.txt"
EndLocal
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=[]" %%a In ('Type "%Temp%\File.Sort.Reverse.txt" ^| Sort') Do Echo.%%b
```